# "Which of the following statement" or "which of the following statements"?

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural

I have seen both expressions online. I don't think "which of the following statement" is grammatically correct but I'm not a native speaker so I'm not sure. Which one of them is more reliably correct?

Comment: **which** can only be used when asking to select from at least two, so you are right that statements (plural) is correct. Can you provide a link to an example of the singular?

Comment: @JavaLatte https://www.skillset.com/questions/which-of-the-following-statement-is-true; https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2579714/which-of-the-following-statement-is-true, and many other examples on google.

Comment: @JavaLatte And this example in a book:https://books.google.com/books?id=u1c-DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA13&lpg=PA13&dq=%22which+of+the+following+statement+is%22&source=bl&ots=s3jWbqrEuX&sig=4Hgdp6TbCfz6NO29m7o9MQX2HnI&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwim3ZW-tMfYAhVi0YMKHfo2AqM4ChDoAQhGMAU#v=onepage&q=%22which%20of%20the%20following%20statement%20is%22&f=false

Comment: The examples that you quoted are definitely incorrect. The skillset site has a grammatical error on the home page, and the other examples contain multiple grammatical errors (incorrect plurals, incorrect or missing articles, typos, etc).